# Centos 7 OpenCL Segfaul

Tags: centos, segmentation-fault, 64-bit, opencl

I am trying to install the AMD opencl runtime and libraries on a Centos 7, 64 bit. The machine is in a server room, and i am sshing in. I had to install the xserver before the rpm would would. I have the same problem when i use the guide to install via an rpm which is to avoid the xserver being present.

I got to the point where i can compile the opencl application which generates a binary without errors. However, when i try and run it it segfaults. I get the same problem with the clinfo binary which ships with the AMD sdk. I include what i can get from gdb from clinfo below:

```
Starting program: /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/bin/x86_64/clinfo
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff0d0070c in llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(int, char const* const*, char const*) () from /usr/lib64/libamdocl12cl64.so
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64 libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64 libXau-1.0.8-2.1.el7.x86_64 libXext-1.3.3-3.el7.x86_64 libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 libxcb-1.11-4.el7.x86_64 mesa-libGL-10.6.5-3.20150824.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff0d0070c in llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(int, char const* const*, char const*) () from /usr/lib64/libamdocl12cl64.so
#1  0x00007fffefdf7a8b in OCLLinkPhase(_acl_loader_data_0_8**, _acl_llvm_module_0_8**, unsigned int, _acl_llvm_module_0_8***, _acl_llvm_context_0_8**, _acl_error_enum_0_8*)
    () from /usr/lib64/libamdocl12cl64.so
#2  0x00007fffefdf47bf in if_aclCompile(_acl_compiler_rec_0_8_1*, _acl_bif_rec_0_8_1*, char const*, _acl_type_enum_0_8, _acl_type_enum_0_8, void (*)(char const*, unsigned long)) () from /usr/lib64/libamdocl12cl64.so
#3  0x00007ffff3f2c789 in aclCompile () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#4  0x00007ffff362ef95 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#5  0x00007ffff36532ac in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#6  0x00007ffff35fceff in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#7  0x00007ffff360cff0 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#8  0x00007ffff35f9d1b in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#9  0x00007ffff363793c in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#10 0x00007ffff36396a8 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#11 0x00007ffff3639846 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#12 0x00007ffff35f7dd0 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#13 0x00007ffff3611ce7 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#14 0x00007ffff35e29e3 in clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so
#15 0x00007ffff74c86ee in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libOpenCL.so.1
#16 0x00007ffff74ca537 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libOpenCL.so.1
#17 0x00007ffff70a0bb0 in pthread_once () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff74ca5c7 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libOpenCL.so.1
#19 0x00007ffff74c8685 in ?? () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libOpenCL.so.1
#20 0x00007ffff74c8c81 in clGetPlatformIDs () from /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libOpenCL.so.1
#21 0x000000000040f4c7 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000000407bb2 in ?? ()
#23 0x00007ffff6cf3b15 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#24 0x000000000040e5f1 in ?? ()
```

Any and all help appreciated!